# Multiple C# projects Open multiple VSCode in MacOS

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have two different RestApi projects made in C#.

When I open project A and compile it, there is no problem.
When I want to open project B with new VSCode window, I get the error “No installed .Net SDK”.

I’m exiting VSCode, than
When I open project B and compile it, there is no problem.
When I want to open project A with new VSCode window, I get the error “No installed .Net SDK”.

Can I open and compile two projects in different VSCode windows?

[image: VS Code Error]

Comment: What is the Target type (ie Core or Net)?  Check the project settings in working and non working projects and see what is being used for the target.  You have to have the correct version of Net/Core installed that matches the target.

Comment: The target of all projects is .net7

in Web_API.csproj file like this 

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

Comment: This should not happen with Core.  Do you have same version of Net 7.0 installed in both build and deploy machines.  See : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had same issue as yours. I tried to simulate your problem now.
Are you using third party git apps? I am asking because I have been using Fork and when I open my projects with Fork shortcut. I had same error as yours.

Would you try to open your project windows directly from VSCode?